# Is there a way to programmatically take a screenshot of an Apple TV's (HDMI connected) screen?

Tags: xcode, macos, screenshot, apple-tv

I **can** take a screenshot via *XCODE Devices & Simulators*.

Doing so I just getting it on the Desktop in a few seconds. That suits me perfectly. With one exception.

I want to run just **one** command (*or script if needed*) to do the same thing. In the future I plan to use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) for this if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what you are asking but maybe using the [Glimpse library](https://github.com/wess/Glimpse) will help.